# How to connecting my web application to socket io in frappe (Docker local development)

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, frappe

So I want to connect my web application that was made from react to frappe. I have already installed the socket io client and connected it to the other socket io server. It was successful when I tried to connect socket io frappe(Docker local development). It always showed "Unable to join chat room. ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002". Is there any guide to testing socket io from local? I have already read this wiki https://github.com/frappe/frappe/wiki/How-to-setup-Socketio-for-development-mode

but it's not solving my problem.

[this is an error from socket io client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlLWR.png)

Please anyone help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: You can test socket connection from newer postman version.

Comment: thank you for your comment, is any resource or tutorial to use postman for testing socket connection?

Comment: There you go --> [https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/websocket/]